# Setting CSS Properties Dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm having an issue. I have to design a css button that can be customized by a user on the fly, with a few customization options. They have to be able to add text, change the button colour, change the button size and change how round the borders are. The thing is, my javascript functions to change the borders and the size of the button aren't working. They also make the other functions not work, oddly enough.

I was told to avoid using jQuery.

The Javascript for the size changing function:

```
    function aBc()
    {
        var a = document.getElementById("buttontest");
        if(document.getElementById("smallS").checked)
        {
            a.style.width = 100px;
        }
        else if(document.getElementById("mediumS").checked)
        {
            a.style.width = 150px;
        }
        else if(document.getElementById("largeS").checked)
        {
            a.style.width = 200px;
        }
        else if(document.getElementById("hugeS").checked)
        {
            a.style.width = 300px;
        }
    }
```

The Javascript for the border changing function:

```
    function changeCorners()
    {
        var bordertest;
        bordertest = document.getElementById("buttontest");
        if (document.getElementById("none").checked)
        {
            bordertest.style.borderRadius = 0px;
        }
        else if (document.getElementById("small").checked)
        {
            bordertest.style.borderRadius = 10px;
        }
        else if (document.getElementById("medium").checked)
        {
            bordertest.style.borderRadius = 20px;
        }
        else if (document.getElementById("large").checked)
        {
            bordertest.style.borderRadius = 30px;
        }
        else if (document.getElementById("total").checked)
        {
            bordertest.style.borderRadius = 40px;
        }
    }
```

The HTML for everything:

```
Button Text: <input type="text" onkeydown="changeText(event)" id="bText"><br />
Text Color: <input type="color" id="tColor" name="tColor" value="#3e3e3e" oninput="changeTextColor(tColor.value)"><br />
How Round:  <input type="radio" name="roundness" id="none" checked="checked" onchange=changeCorners()>
            <label for="none">Square</label>
            <input type="radio" name="roundness" id="small" onchange=changeCorners()>
            <label for="small">Small Roundness</label>
            <input type="radio" name="roundness" id="medium" onchange=changeCorners()>
            <label for="medium">Medium Roundness</label>
            <input type="radio" name="roundness" id="large" onchange=changeCorners()>
            <label for="large">Large Roundness</label>
            <input type="radio" name="roundness" id="total" onchange=changeCorners()>
            <label for="total">Completely Round</label><br />
Background Color: <input type="color" id="backColor" name="backColor" value="#dddddd" oninput="changeBgColor(backColor.value)"><br />
Shadow Color: <input type="color" id="shadColor" name="shadColor" value="#888888" oninput="changeShadColor(shadColor.value)"><br />
Button Size: <input type="radio" name="size" id="smallS" checked="checked" onchange=aBc()>
             <label for="smallS">Small</label>
             <input type="radio" name="size" id="mediumS" onchange=aBc()>
             <label for="mediumS">Medium</label>
             <input type="radio" name="size" id="largeS" onchange=aBc()>
             <label for="largeS">Large</label>
             <input type="radio" name="size" id="hugeS" onchange=aBc()>
             <label for="hugeS">Extra Large</label><br />

<p><input type="button" value="" class="test1" id="buttontest"></p>
```

Comment: `s = 0px` and similar is not valid JavaScript; it will result in a Parse Error.

Comment: i think you should create a jsfiddle link so we can fix into that only :)

Comment: @j08691 Adding the quotations fixed it. The dangers of learning as I go, I guess. And yup, my boss told me to avoid jQuery.

Comment: OK, I'll add that as an answer then. And tell your boss I said you should be allowed to use jQuery, and if he has any problem with that he can call me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote your property values.

Things like `a.style.width = 100px;` should be `a.style.width = "100px";`